# DC accurate low pass filter

Tags: dc, filter, low-pass

I need to make an **dc accurate low pass filter.** Actually, I need to measure the dc/average value of a waveform. Suggest me some good and practical 0hz low pass filters. That is, the filter that can block other frequency waveforms but pass only dc component of a wave.

The waveform can be as:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well technically the signal will never be completely DC. If we think in terms of rise time instead of hz, what do you want the rise time of the filer to be for a step signal? 1 second? 1 hour? 30 days?

Comment: Actually the signal (of which I need to measure dc) isn't dc. But, is actually a distorted signal. And, I need to measure the average value of that signal.

Comment: Average over what timespan?

Comment: How long do you want to wait, from the start of the operation, before getting your first measurement? (since you missed Drew's point entirely). And how accurate do you want the measurement to be?

Comment: Averaged over one complete cycle. Here, the accuracy is utmost important. Timespan may be some few seconds.

Comment: You have still failed to give a specification for what you want. (1) What is the frequency? (2) How long are you prepared to wait for a reading and at what tolerance? e.g. "99% of true value in 17.3 s." (3) What is the peak voltage range? (4) Why do you want an average reading instead of a true RMS reading? (5) What is the relevance of the chopped sine-wave diagram? Please [edit] your question to write a proper specification.

Comment: I think what you're misunderstanding is that you really have two very different options. You can record the waveform, pick the start and end of the cycle and compute the average. Alternatively you can use a low pass filter that integrates over many cycles to produce an average value which you could record.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to average over "one complete cycle" and "accuracy is utmost important" then you don't want to use a low-pass filter. You need to sample and digitize the waveform with the highest sample rate and highest accuracy ADC you can get. You will need to use software to detect the beginning and end of each cycle, and calculate the average value mathematically.

Answer (score 1):

For a measurement in "a few" seconds you want a time constant of about 1 second, or an -3dB frequency of 1/(2*pi) Hz.

Then the accuracy required determines the definition of "a few" : a first order filter will approach its final value within 1% after 5 time constants, so to average within 1% will take 5 time constants or 5 seconds if you chose RC = 1 second.